# use Gsm Sim800L To Publish data using MQtt

Tags: mqtt, gsm, publish-subscriber

I have a Module Gsm Sim800L and I must Publish Data to a nodeRed Server Of IBM Bluemix.

I used the library (Arduino MQTT Library for SIM800 GSM Modem) at this Link : 
https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/arduino-mqtt-library-for-sim800-gsm-modem/

The Problem is that I don't know what I must change to connect and publish to a IBM BlueMix Server Via MQTT.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site!  Your question is not very clear as it stands.  Please [edit] to clarify what the exact issue is and what you have tried.  (For instance, what libraries?)

Comment: Hey Sir THanks For your Comment ,i'm sorry because i am Beginner , So i use this library in this Link : https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/arduino-mqtt-library-for-sim800-gsm-modem/comment-page-1/?unapproved=3970&moderation-hash=02b14917adae4fbe8ea2ac552f5a9e01&blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog
The Problem Is that  i don't know what i must Change to connect and Publish to a IBM BlueMix Server Via MQTT , 
If you Have Any Suggestion Tell Me

Comment: Okay, thanks!  Please [edit] that into your question.  Also,out will be important to know exactly what's not working...  As you question stands, it's rather info unclear what errors you might be facing etc.  Thanks!

Comment: @NadjibJipou Would be good if you could post some of your code.  The connect function is clearly defined, maybe you need help there?